# Hockey-stick identity with terms of alternating sign $\sum_{k=0}^{m} (-)^k \binom{k+m}{k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I'm currently looking at Hermite polynomials, looking at sums of the form $\sum_k \frac1{(\gamma_i-\gamma_k)^{n}}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, and an identity that popped up is of the form
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{m} (-)^k \binom{k+m}{k},
\end{equation}
which reminds me a lot about hockeystick.

So, I found a closed form of this in terms of exotic functions:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^m (-)^k \binom{k+m}{k} = \frac1{2^{m+1}} \left[1- (-)^m \frac{(2m)!}{m!(m-1)!}B\left(\frac12,m,-2m\right)\right] + (-)^{m} \binom{2m}{m},
\end{equation}
but it's not very insightful how the result depends on $m$, notably because of the Beta function on the RHS.

Does anybody know how to improve on this answer? Either with another derivation or with a nice representation of the Beta function (e.g. with another binomial coefficient, or some elementary function)?

Comment: The Beta function always evaluates to a rational number, so it could be simplified. Where does the $(-)^n$ notation come from? You can also try solving in terms of a [Gauss Hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) and [use these decomposition formulas](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/)

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for joining! $(-)^n$ is just $(-1)^n$, it's a relic of my time with my first university professor.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Re: the hypergeometric idea: the closest I can find on a whim is Prudnikov p 465, eqn 164 of "More Special Functions", but it yields an enormous system of recurrent equations that seems to make the situation worse than it already is.

Comment: Possible partial answer: the beta function integral has the form \begin{equation}(-1)^{n-1}\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(n)\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-t)^\ell}{\ell!}  \prod_{m=0}^{\ell-1}(2n-m)}{4^n\Gamma\left(n+\frac12\right)(1-t)^{2n}}\end{equation}
which has a nice denominator for $t=1/2$.

Comment: Another update: the absolute value of the summation appears to be related to Fine's sequence. See oeis.org/A014300

Comment: I have only seen the notation $(-)^n$ in  British math books from the early 20th century. Did you come to 2022 in a time machine? (If so, I regret to tell you that the Spanish flu has been replaced by something more... interesting.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some additional information which might be useful. Calculating the first few terms of the sequence of numbers
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_m=\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^k\binom{k+m}{k}\qquad\qquad m\geq 0}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
gives
\begin{align*}
\left(a_m\right)_{m\geq 0}=(1,     -1,      4,    -13,     46,   -166,    610,  -2\,269,\ldots)\tag{2}
\end{align*}

**OEIS A026641:**

The sequence $a_m, m\geq 0$ is not stored in OEIS, but we find the sequence *[A026641](http://oeis.org/A026641)* of absolute values
\begin{align*}
\left((-1)^ma_m\right)_{m\geq 0}=(1,     1,      4,    13,     46,   166,    610,  2\,269,\ldots)
\end{align*}
giving the number $(-1)^ma_m$ of nodes of even outdegree (including leaves) in all ordered trees with $m$ edges. We can derive from the stated information the generating function
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_mz^m}&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^k\binom{k+m}{k}z^m\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4z}}\,\frac{2}{3-\sqrt{1+4z}}\qquad\qquad |z|<\frac{1}{4}}
\end{align*}
We can  also derive some nice formulas of (1) for instance from one of the formulas from Richard Choulet we get
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_m=(-1)^m\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\binom{2m-k}{m}\qquad\qquad m\geq 0}
\end{align*}

**OEIS A188289:**

Another closely related sequence can be found when we skip the summand $k=0$ in (1) and consider
\begin{align*}
a_m-1=\sum_{\color{blue}{k=1}}^{m}(-1)^k\binom{k+m}{k}\qquad\qquad m\geq 0
\end{align*}
We get
\begin{align*}
\left(a_m-1\right)_{m\geq 0}=(0,     -2,      3,    -14,     45,   -167,    609,  -2\,270,\ldots)
\end{align*}
and find again the sequence of absolute values of $a_m-1, m\geq 0$ in OEIS as *[A188289](http://oeis.org/A188289)*. We derive for instance from the first stated formula
\begin{align*}
(-1)^m\left(a_m-1\right)=\binom{2m}{m}-(-1)^m-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{2k}{m-1}
\end{align*}
from which the nice identity
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_m=(-1)^m\left(\binom{2m}{m}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{2k}{m-1}\right)\qquad\qquad m\geq 0}
\end{align*}
follows. Note in the last line the sum is empty if $m=0$ and all terms $\binom{2k}{m-1}$ with $k<\left\lfloor\frac{m-1}{2}\right\rfloor$ vanish.

Comment: If $B(z)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}$ and $C(z)=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$, the generating functions for the central binomial coefficients, Catalan numbers, then this generating function is $\dfrac{B(z)}{1+zC(z)}\circ(-z)=\dfrac{B(z)F(z)}{C(z)}\circ(-z)=\dfrac{(B(z)+1)F(z)}{2}\circ(-z)$, where $F(z)=\dfrac{C(z)}{1+zC(z)}$ is the generating function for Fine numbers [A000957](https://oeis.org/A000957) (without the initial zero).

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein: It looks elegant. It might be worth a separate answer.

Comment: I think this would make sense if I figure out a bijection (probably, some sort of inclusion-exclusion argument) that shows that $\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^k\binom{2m-k}{m}$ counts nodes of even outdegree in all ordered trees with $m$ edges. The rest of is a pretty straightforward manipulation of tree generating functions.

Comment: Tree ogf manipulation: Start with a tree. Its ogf is $C(z)$. Choose a marked vertex, that yields $(zC(z))'=B(z)$. Remove the subtree rooted at that vertex to make it a leaf, i.e. divide by $C(z)$. Now attach an even number of planted trees, i.e. multiply by $\dfrac{1}{1-(zC(z))^2}=\dfrac{C(z)}{1+zC(z)}=F(z)$.

Comment: It looks like $\binom{2m-k}{m}$ counts the total number of vertices of degree at least $k$ in all ordered trees on $m$ edges. From there, I think, it's some version of the "glove" bijection to get to the binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

*What follows is more of a comment.* We can find the OGF using the residue operator. We have

$$S_m = \sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k {k+m\choose k}$$

and we use an Iverson bracket

$$\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k {k+m\choose k} [[k\le m]]
= \sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k {k+m\choose k} [z^m] \frac{z^k}{1-z}
\\ = [z^m] \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1+z)^{m+1}}
= \; \underset{z}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{z^{m+1}} \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1+z)^{m+1}}.$$

Now we put $z=(-1+\sqrt{1+4w})/2$ so that $z(1+z)=w$ and $dz = 
1/\sqrt{1+4w} \; dw$ to get

$$\; \underset{w}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{w^{m+1}} \frac{2}{3-\sqrt{1+4w}}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4w}}.$$

Comment: Elegant derivation of the generating function. I like the clever representation of the Iverson brackets via a geometric series. (+1)

Comment: @epi163sqrt Also, there is an [algorithm](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) to find $S_m$ and prove that it doesn't have an elementary closed form, in some precise sense. If $R[y] = (2 m + 4) y_{m + 2} + (7 m + 10) y_{m + 1} - (4 m + 6) y_m$, then $S_m$ and
$$F_m = 2^{-m - 1} + (-1)^m 2^{-m - 1} \binom {2 m + 1} {m + 1}
 {_2 F_1}(-m, m + 1; m + 2; -1)$$
satisfy the same recurrence relation $R[y] = 0$ with the same initial conditions, so $S_m  = F_m$. The only elementary solution of $R[y] = 0$ is $y_m = C \cdot 2^{-m}$, so $S_m$ is not elementary.

Comment: @Maxim Maybe you should make this comment into an answer?