# Sum of Binomial Coefficients Modulo Prime Power

Tags: algorithms, binomial-coefficients, computational-mathematics

Let $a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-i}\binom{n+i}{i}$. I'd like to ask how to compute $a_n$ modulo $p^e$ fast where $p$ is a prime?

Comment: I would suggest reading [Lucas' Theorem for Prime Powers](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669813801229).

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4393643/hockey-stick-identity-with-terms-of-alternating-sign-sum-k-0m-k-bino